# Laravel 5.4 with datatables

Tags: php, laravel, datatable

I have added this package https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables into my package and i am trying to use it in my application.

This is the view

```
@section('content')
    <table class="table table-bordered" id="users-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Emp No</th>
                 <th>Birth Date</th>
                  <th>First Name</th>
                   <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Gender</th>
                     <th>Hire Date</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
@stop

@push('scripts')

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $('#users-table').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        responsive: true,
        ajax: 'http://localhost:8000/tasks',
        columns: [
            { data: 'emp_no', name: 'emp_no' }
            { data: 'birth_date', name: 'birth_date' },
            { data: 'first_name', name: 'first_name' },
            { data: 'last_name', name: 'last_name' },
            { data: 'gender', name: 'gender' },
            { data: 'hire_date', name: 'hire_date' }
        ]
    });
});
</script>

@endpush
@endsection
```

This is the route

```
Route::get('tasks', 'PrototypeController@getTasks')->name('datatable.tasks');
```

This is the controller

```
public function getTasks()
    {
       return Datatables::of(Employees::query())->make(true);
       //returns json
    }
```

This code loads the view containining the datatables.

The url http://localhost:8000/tasks returns the json in the web browser but the datatable is never rendered in my view. When i check in my view, there are no browser errors.

What could be the problem?.

Answer (score 0):

Create two method, one display our view and other method that will process our datatables ajax request.

**Display our view**

```
public function viewTasks()
{
    return view('Tasks.index');
}
```

**Process our datatables ajax request**

```
public function getTasks()
{
    return Datatables::of(Employees::query())->make(true);
}
```

Reference Link :- [Yajra Datatable](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/starter)

Comment: I already have the controller that displays the view `Route::get('bulkOutbox', 'PrototypeController@bulkOutbox');`
 and the other to process the ajax requests `Route::get('tasks', 'PrototypeController@getTasks')->name('datatable.tasks');`

Comment: first bulkOutbox with rendered this view and run that url http://localhost:8000/bulkOutbox

Comment: I am loading bulkOutbox first and still displays nothing. If you have mysql sample database installed, you can test it out.

Comment: This is totally bizarre, there are no jquery errors whatsoever.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142560/discussion-between-swaroop-suthar-and-geoffrey-isle).

Answer (score 0):

You should change in your controller. Add code below for showing data table:

```
 public function task()
    {
        return view('datatables.Index');
    }
```

Change in `web.php` file for add new route:

```
Route::get( 'employee','PrototypeController@task');
```

Add data table CDN and bootstrap also

```
<link href="https://datatables.yajrabox.com/css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://datatables.yajrabox.com/css/datatables.bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,300|Open+Sans:400,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet'
          type='text/css'>
```

Comment: And I think ,You should Change Blade file . Because '@endsection' stop before' @sctipt'. If You create master.blade.php .. Thanks